# Logic error in remove duplicates in a vector while preserving the order function

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates

```
void vectorDeduplicator(std::vector<std::string>& inputVector){ 
     for(int i = 0; i < inputVector.size() - 1; i++){
          for(int x = 1; x <= inputVector.size() - 1; x++)
                if(inputVector.at(i) == inputVector.at(x) && i != x){
                inputVector.erase(inputVector.begin() + x);    
          }
     }
}
Input: 1 1 2 2 4 4 3 3 1 1 3 3 3 2 2
Output: [1,2,4,1,3,2]
```

You can see the function I'm trying to use to remove duplicates inside of a **vector**. It works when duplicates are adjacent. I wouldn't like to use a faster and an efficient method without knowing anything about it that already exists within the standard library or anything else. I'd like to learn the algorithm behind it as this is for learning purposes.

Comment: Populate a temporary vector, then copy the temporary back to the original.  There is no need to do all of the erasing.  What if the vector had thousands of elements?  Each time you erase, the vector has to shrink by one.  Use some logic to populate a temp vector instead.

Comment: `x <= inputVector.size() - 1` is a complicated way of saying `x < inputVector.size()`.

Comment: If you need a container that explicilty doesn't have duplicates you can also use std::set

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie If I understood correctly, you are saying that I should populate another vector, iterate through the first vector to exclude duplicates, and then copy it back to the original. Am I right? If I do that wouldn't it copy the duplicates again to the temp vector If my algorithm is flawed?

Comment: @ool123 -- What I am saying is to scan the original array, and *use a little logic*  to populate the temporary array with the non-duplicate value.  In other words, your approach should be changed -- it is flawed in the ways I mentioned.  Work it out on paper -- create the original vector, and "build up" the temporary vector with the unique item.

Comment: do you need a stable solution? Must the remaining elements be in same order as in the input?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Can be done without extra memory [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6df27c6fbfa5050e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you ignore one value as you erase. You need to decrement x:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void vectorDeduplicator(std::vector<int>& inputVector)
{ 
     for(int i = 0; i < inputVector.size() - 1; i++)
     {
          for(int x = 1; x < inputVector.size(); x++)
          {
                if(inputVector.at(i) == inputVector.at(x) && i != x)
                {
                    inputVector.erase(inputVector.begin() + x);
                    x--; // go one back because you erased one value
                }
          }

        // to debug
        for(const auto& x : inputVector)
            std::cout << x << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
     }
}

int main(){

    std::vector<int> vector{1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2};

    vectorDeduplicator(vector);

    // output
    for(const auto& x : vector)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    

    return 0;
}
```

The output then is:

```
1 2 2 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 
1 2 4 4 3 3 3 3 3 
1 2 4 3 3 3 3 3 
1 2 4 3 
1 2 4 3
```

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Wouldn't it stay positive no matter what? Because every time you decrement x you'll also be incrementing x. So x will always be  greater than 0

Comment: Besides, nothing wrong with decrementing unsigned.

Comment: @bipll d'oh right. I was confused. No issue here. I'll remove comments